# Como ordenar un areglo por medio de su propiedad en javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var apartamentos = [{
  fecha_ingreso: "10/10/11", 
  tipo_inmueble:"En venta", 
  precio: "1000", 
  titulo: "Edificio",
  metraje: 3,
  ubicacion: '14 Avenida 16-01 Zona 10. Guatemala, Guatemala',
  zona: "Zona 3", 
  habitaciones: 3, 
   parqueos: 5, 
  banos: 2, 
  tipo_techo: "Balcon", 
 categoria: 'Gimnasio'
  }]
```

**Intente con esto pero no funcionó:**

```
function filtrarporfecha(){
var ordenarpor = $('input:radio[name=ordenarpor]:checked').val();

if(ordenarpor == "nuevo"){
    apartamentos.sort();


}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La funcion sort recibe otra funcion como parametro.  Puedes customisar el orden usando cualquier propiedad.  Te dejo un ejemplo, espero que te sirva chapin.

```js
var apartamentos = [{
  fecha_ingreso: "10/10/11", 
  tipo_inmueble:"En venta", 
  precio: "1000", 
  titulo: "Edificio",
  metraje: 3,
  ubicacion: '14 Avenida 16-01 Zona 10. Guatemala, Guatemala'  
  },
  {
  fecha_ingreso: "11/10/11", 
  tipo_inmueble:"En venta", 
  precio: "1000", 
  titulo: "Edificio",
  metraje: 3,
  ubicacion: '14 Avenida 16-01 Zona 10. Guatemala, Guatemala'  
}]

function filtrarporfecha(){
      
    apartamentos.sort(function(a,b){ 
    
        return new Date(b.fecha_ingreso) - new Date(a.fecha_ingreso);
    });    
      
}
    
filtrarporfecha();
console.log(apartamentos);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias brother

Answer (score 1):

Sintaxis arr.sort([compareFunction]) 
Descripción: Si no se provee compareFunction, los elementos son
ordenados convirtiéndolos a strings y comparando la posición del valor
Unicode de dichos strings. Ejemplo:

"Cherry"
viene antes que "banana" . En un ordenamiento numérico, 9
está antes que 80, pero dado que los números son convertidos a strings y
ordenados según el valor Unicode, el
resultado será "80" antes que "9".

```
var frutas = ['guindas', 'manzanas', 'bananas'];    
frutas.sort(); // ['bananas', 'guindas', 'manzanas']

var puntos = [1, 10, 2, 21];    
puntos.sort(); // [1, 10, 2, 21]
```

// Tenga en cuenta que 10 viene antes que 2
// porque '10' viene antes que '2' según la
posición del valor Unicode.

```
var cosas = ['word', 'Word', '1 Word', '2 Words'];    
cosas.sort();  // ['1 Word', '2 Words', 'Word', 'word']
```

// En Unicode, los números vienen antes que las
letras mayúsculas // y estas vienen antes que las letras
minúsculas.