# ordenar un array con objetos

Tags: javascript, array, date, object

Me gustaria poder ordenar un array entero de mayor a menor con la fecha que se encuentra dentro de un objeto en el array;

```html
    var datos = [ {
    id:"12",
    usuarioA:"1",
    usuarioB:"2",
    mensaje:"Hola mi amor",
    date:"2017-01-19",
    remitente:"Andrey Homez",
    destinatario:"Paola Gonzales",
    CVX:"Paola Gonzales"
  },
  {
    id:"13",
    usuarioA:"1",
    usuarioB:"3",
    mensaje:"dsadsa",
    date:"2019-08-01",
    remitente:"Andrey Homez",
    destinatario:"Felipe Gomez",
    CVX:"Felipe Gomez"
  },
  {
    id:"11",
    usuarioA:"1",
    usuarioB:"1",
    mensaje:"dsadas",
    date:"2018-01-23",
    remitente:"Andrey Homez",
    destinatario:"Andrey Homez",
    CVX:"Andrey Homez"
  }
];
```

Que el primero array me quede de esta forma para despues yo poder trabajar con el sin tener que preocuparme de fechas, muchas gracias!

```html
var datos = [ {
    id:"12",
    usuarioA:"1",
    usuarioB:"2",
    mensaje:"Hola mi amor",
    date:"2018-03-9",
    remitente:"Andrey Homez",
    destinatario:"Paola Gonzales",
    CVX:"Paola Gonzales"},{

    id:"13",
    usuarioA:"1",
    usuarioB:"3",
    mensaje:"dsadsa",
    date:"2017-11-21",
    remitente:"Andrey Homez",
    destinatario:"Felipe Gomez",
    CVX:"Felipe Gomez"
  },{
    id:"11",
    usuarioA:"1",
    usuarioB:"1",
    mensaje:"dsadas",
    date:"2016-04-13",
    remitente:"Andrey Homez",
    destinatario:"Andrey Homez",
    CVX:"Andrey Homez"
  }
];
```

Comment: Conteste una respuesta similar aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171821/como-ordenar-un-areglo-por-medio-de-su-propiedad-en-javascript/171827#171827

Comment: si deberias revisar su respuesta de @alanfcm.