# NodeJs ¿Cómo ordenar una array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ordenamiento

hola mi problema es el siguiente, tengo una array de objetos que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
let array_de_objetos = [];

let archivo_uno = {
name: prueba, // Nombre del archivo
ts: 2076-11-29T08:54:34.955Z //ctime: La última vez que el fichero se modificó ...
}

let archivo_dos = {
name: prueba_dos,
ts: 2076-12-29T09:54:34.955Z
}

array_de_objetos.push(archivo_uno, archivo_dos);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar los datos dentro de esa array de forma que los ficheros más viejos queden de primero en la array, para esto pensé en usar la función (sort) pero no tengo claro como hacerlo, alguien podría ayudarme? gracias!

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? En el sitio hay varias respuestas al respecto.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como ordenar un areglo por medio de su propiedad en javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171821/como-ordenar-un-areglo-por-medio-de-su-propiedad-en-javascript)